# How does router advertisement in IPv6 avoid IP conflict?

Tags: router, ipv6, dhcpv6, icmpv6

If a router advertisement sends the range of subnet, and the client can choose an IP from it, how is there no conflict with another client that has chosen the same address?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A host performs **Duplicate Address Detection (DAD)** before actually activating the given address on the interface

[RFC 2462](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2462#section-5.4) has to say about this:

> 5.4.  Duplicate Address Detection
>
> Duplicate Address Detection is performed on unicast addresses prior
> to assigning them to an interface whose DupAddrDetectTransmits
> variable is greater than zero. Duplicate Address Detection MUST take
> place on all unicast addresses, regardless of whether they are
> obtained through stateful, stateless or manual configuration, with
> the exception of the following cases:   [...]

The original RFC was updated/modernized by [RFC 4429](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4429) and further on by [RFC 7527](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7527)

---

**EDIT**
To nitpick a bit: the correct sequence of RFCs is more precisely:

[RFC 1971](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1971), obsoleted by [RFC 2462](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2462), obsoleted by [RFC 4862](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862), updated by RFC [7527](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7527)